# T-SQL How to transpose a column into row by row_number SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a SQL server table load from web service. The structure of this table is not what I want.

My table looks like this:

```
RN     Text
1      ID1
2      Title1
3      Item1
4      ID2
5      Title2
6      Item2
7      ID3
8      Title3
...    ...
```

Result Table should like this:

```
ID     Title    Item
ID1    Title1   Item1
ID2    Title2   Item2
ID3    Title3   Item3
...    ...      ...
```

I have thousands of items data in a single column, each item data contains within 3 rows. How can I transpose(rotate) it into a single row?

I really appreciate for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one trick to do it

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
               seq = ( Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY [RN]) - 1 ) / 3 + 1                    
         FROM   Yourtable)
SELECT ID = Max(CASE ([RN] - 1) % 3 + 1 WHEN 1 THEN [Text] END),
       Title = Max(CASE ([RN] - 1) % 3 + 1 WHEN 2 THEN [Text] END),
       Item = Max(CASE ([RN] - 1) % 3 + 1 WHEN 3 THEN [Text] END)
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY seq
```

**Note :** This assumes `RN` is sequential, if no then

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                seq = ( Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY [RN]) - 1 ) / 3 + 1,
                grp = ( Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY [RN]) - 1 ) % 3 + 1                       
         FROM   Yourtable)
SELECT ID = Max(CASE grp WHEN 1 THEN [Text] END),
       Title = Max(CASE grp WHEN 2 THEN [Text] END),
       Item = Max(CASE grp WHEN 3 THEN [Text] END)
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY seq
```

Comment: Shamefully oversimplified my answer (removed)  +1 for extra steps to ensure the proper sequence

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! It really solves my problem. Just out of curious, why you add MAX in front of CASE? What's that for?